# Приложение зависает из за CountDownTimer после отправки http-запроса

Tags: android, retrofit, countdowntimer

Я делаю экран с подтверждением телефона через код по смс. После того, как я ввожу номер и нажимаю на кнопку для получения кода, кнопка блокируется на 60 секунд и `CountDownTimer` отсчитывает это время, отображая секунды на кнопке.
После того, как я получил код по смс, я ввожу его в поле для кода и нажимаю другую кнопку "Подтвердить телефон". Отправляется запрос для подтверждения телефона и приложение зависает. Не понимаю в чем причина. Запрос отправляется асинхронно через `Retrofit` методом `enqueue()`. 
Код ответа на запрос кода выглядит следующим образом:

```
private Callback<ResponseModelForList<String>> getCodeCallback() {
        return new Callback<ResponseModelForList<String>>() {
            @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<ResponseModelForList<String>> call,
                                   @NonNull Response<ResponseModelForList<String>> response) {
                if (response.body().getErrorCode() != 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(
                            AccountActivity.this,
                            ErrorMessageManager.getErrorMessage(response.body().getErrorCode()),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    buttonGetCode.setEnabled(true);
                } else {
                    new CountDownTimer(TIME_FOR_WAITING_BETWEEN_SENDING_CODE, TIMER_TICK_INTERVAL) {
                        public void onTick(final long millisUntilFinished) {
                            App.Log("millis: " + Long.toString(millisUntilFinished));
                            buttonGetCode.setText(LabelsFormatter
                                    .getCodeButtonLabel(
                                            millisUntilFinished / TIMER_TICK_INTERVAL));
                        }

                        public void onFinish() {
                            buttonGetCode.setEnabled(true);
                            buttonGetCode.setText("Получить");
                        }
                    }.start();


                    Toast.makeText(AccountActivity.this,
                            "Код подтверждения выслан через SMS-сообщение",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<ResponseModelForList<String>> call,
                                  @NonNull Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(
                        AccountActivity.this,
                        ErrorMessageManager.getErrorMessage(500),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                buttonGetCode.setEnabled(true);
            }
        };
```

Код ответа при нажатии на кнопку "Подтвердить телефон"

```
private Callback<ResponseModelForList<String>> getConfirmPhoneCallback() {
        return new Callback<ResponseModelForList<String>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<ResponseModelForList<String>> call,
                                   @NonNull Response<ResponseModelForList<String>> response) {
                if (response.body().getErrorCode() != 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(AccountActivity.this,
                            ErrorMessageManager.getErrorMessage(response.body().getErrorCode()),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    User user = App.getUserData();
                    user.setPhone(phone);
                    App.setUserData(user);
                    App.initPhoneConfirmation();
                    Toast.makeText(
                            AccountActivity.this,
                            "Телефон успешно подтвержден",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<ResponseModelForList<String>> call,
                                  @NonNull Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(AccountActivity.this,
                        ErrorMessageManager.getErrorMessage(500),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        };
```

Код нажатия на кнопку подтверждения телефона:

```
@Click(R.id.buttonChangePhone)
    void onButtonChangePhone() {
        String code = editTextCode.getText().toString();
        if (!code.isEmpty()) {
            Api.getSource().confirmPhone(new ConfirmPhoneRequestData(Integer.parseInt(code)))
                    .enqueue(getConfirmPhoneCallback());
        }
    }
```

Код нажатия на кнопку получения кода:

```
@Click(R.id.buttonGetCode)
    void onButtonGetCodeClick() {
        buttonGetCode.setEnabled(false);
        phone = editTextPhone.getRawText();
        Api.getSource().changePhone(new ChangePhoneRequestData(
                LabelsFormatter.getPhoneFormatLabel(phone)))
                .enqueue(getChangePhoneCallback());
        buttonGetCode.setEnabled(false);

    }
```

Я не очень хорошо шарю в потоках, поэтому нуждаюсь в помощи. Заранее благодарю!

Comment: Зачем Вы этот код показали - он ведь отрабатывает? Как я понял беда начинается с нажатия кнопки "Подтвердить телефон" - вот с её обработчика и нужно начинать разбираться. Да, и что означает зависает - ANR или просто ничего не происходит?

Comment: Теперь при нажатии на получение кода вылетает ошибка java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()